# How to handle multivalued fields in MYSQL database for movie collection?

Tags: sql, excel, database

I have a large number of movies and TV series, which I currently keep track of in an MS Excel worksheet. Due to the large number of records and various data required, it is no longer a convenient option, so I want to switch to a MYSQL database, accessed through a GUI programmed in Java using Netbeans IDE.

I have the following tables in Excel:
**Media_Library,
To_Be_Watched,
Statistics,
Wish_List,
Orders**

Each film and TV series in my collection is in the Media_Library table, which has the following fields:

- Sorting_Title
- Title
- Collection
- Genre
- Release_Year
- Director
- Age_Rating
- Country
- Runtime (min)
- Watched
- Media_Type
- Format

For example: *'Alien 2', 'Aliens', 'Alien: Anthology', 'Action/Horror/Sci-Fi', 1986, 'James Cameron', 'M', 'America', 137, 'Yes', 'Movie', '4K UHD'*

I'm stuck on what to do for the following fields: **Genre, Director, Country, Runtime**
Those 4 fields can each have multiple values, and I don't know how best to handle that; e.g. most films only have 1 runtime, but many have multiple (2 of the films have 4 different cuts). Also anthology films can have something like 6 different directors. I want to include all relevant genres, directors, countries and runtimes, but I don't know how to best do that.

I've tried adding a column for each value; **genre1, genre2, ...** This results in many blank values though. In the spreadsheet in Excel I put all applicable genres in a single field as one string, e.g. **'comedy/horror'**.

What would be the easiest way to resolve this issue? Can I do a many-to-many relationship to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put a hard limit on the amount of genres.

For instance, while you may want the user to be able to enter as many genres as they want, is it rational to go above 20 genres? That doesn't make much sense and will only make searches much more time intensive.

For other possible duplicates, you can do something like this (in sqlite3 at least):

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Directors
        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        director TEXT,
        UNIQUE(director) ON CONFLICT IGNORE)


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file
        (file_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        filename TEXT,
        director_id INTEGER,
        watched INTEGER,
        FOREIGN KEY (director_id)
            REFERENCES Directors (id)
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
                ON DELETE SET NULL)
```

It doesn't matter if more than one genre have the same director, just as long as the 'file' table knows which one it's referencing and staying updated.

The 'watched' column holds a type of value that doesn't make sense to create an individual table for. For instance, say a song's track number is 2. Creating a table just for track numbers to reference doesn't make sense because you're going to spend a point in that table, then spend another point in the 'file' table to reference. So, just spend 1 point and put in the 'file'.

https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-foreign-key/

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you would add a second table, Directors, for instance, and then you relate that back to the movie title.  You will need a uniqueID for the movie, and you do a join where that uniqueID is referenced in the Directors table, something like this working demo (not all fields were included in my demo):

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e8d73bc798767b56b974ab4ebd30517

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, d.director
FROM Media_Library m
JOIN Directors d ON (m.id = d.mediaID);
```

or to concatenate the directors:

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, group_concat(d.director) as directors
FROM Media_Library m
JOIN Directors d ON (m.id = d.mediaID)
GROUP BY m.id;
```

Usually when you make this kind of relationship you will define a foreign key restraint, creating a link between the primary key of one table and a key (or keys) in another.  In this case, the link is between id in Media_Library and mediaID in directors, so you would alter the create statement like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Directors (
  id int not null auto_increment, 
  mediaID int, 
  director varchar(50), 
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (mediaID) REFERENCES Media_Library(id)
);
```

The foreign key is not strictly necessary, but it can reinforce database integrity.  The ins and outs of foreign keys are out of scope for this answer, but you should probably read about them.

It is also possible to store the data in a JSON field since v5.7, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test.Media_Library (id int not null auto_increment, title varchar (50), director JSON, PRIMARY KEY (id));

INSERT INTO test.Media_Library (title, director) VALUES 
('Alien', json_array("Scott", "Scorsese")), 
('The Alienist', '["Tarantino", "Nolan", "Kubrick"]'), 
('Alien 2', '["Scott"]');

SELECT * FROM test.Media_Library;
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tG1SZorEHEYi5cYwgXjPeY/1

In the second query in that fiddle, I select only the first director from the list:

```
SELECT id, title, director->>'$[0]' as firstDirector
FROM Media_Library;
```

There are advantages to storing data this way, but there are tradeoffs, and unless you know what you are doing or you have a specific reason to be using JSON fields (for instance, you are getting the data from an api as JSON and you just want to use it as is), I would stick with the join method.  Also, storing arrays is inherently non-normal (read about database normalization, a quick overview on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).